# How to set AWS RDS Postgres time zone

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to customize the time zone in my AWS RDS postgres database (for always, not just the current session).

I send queries to the database using a connection made by a java web app running on elastic beanstalk.

I tried: `SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';` and `ALTER DATABASE your_db_name SET timezone TO 'UTC';` but nothing happened.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Timezone parameter in a Postgres Parameter Group and associate the Parameter Group with your RDS instance.
AWS provide a list of available parameters for Postgres:
[Common DBA Tasks - Postgres](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Parameters.html)

Readme on how to work with Parameter Groups:
[Working with Parameter Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithDBInstanceParamGroups.html)

Example CLI:

```
# Create a new Parameter Group. Assumes you are using Postgres v14 as the DB engine
aws rds create-db-parameter-group \
    --db-parameter-group-name mydbparametergroup \
    --db-parameter-group-family postgres14 \
    --description "My new parameter group"

# Associate the Parameter Group with your RDS instance
aws rds modify-db-instance \
    --db-instance-identifier your_db_name \
    --db-parameter-group-name mydbparametergroup \
    --apply-immediately

# Modify the Timezone Parameter
aws rds modify-db-parameter-group \
    --db-parameter-group-name mydbparametergroup \
    --parameters "ParameterName=Timezone,ParameterValue="UTC",ApplyMethod=immediate"
```